# How to add user profile picture to Asp.net Membership (aspnet_Profile) table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-profile

I want to save user profile picture to **asp.net_profile** table in Sqlserver, please help me how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't save images directly to the database, it's bad for performance and will eat up a lot of space. Instead, save it to a filesystem or cloud storage (S3, Azure Blob Storage) and store a reference/url to the image inside the profile.

You can then leverage something like a CDN to serve up the picture, and save a great deal on bandwidth.

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for more in depth reasons.

Comment: I accept your suggestion, but i have only 3-4 user profile pictures to store in DB please let me know how to do that to store in Asp.net Membership (aspnet_Profile) table?

Comment: Actually, there is a field name PropertyValueBinary with data time Image in Aspnet_profile table, i want to save my userprofile picture there.